# Listing webpage assets via CLI

Tags: command-line

When you browse in a webpage with a browser, after the code of the page is downloaded, the browser downloads all the assets (CSSs, JSs and images).

Is there a way I can list all the URL of the assets of a page (internal and external assets)?

The idea is to monitor changes on the external and internal assets.

Comment: I posted a solution which prints the URLs of external resources. I wasn't sure what you meant by "internal assets", so I just output the body/text/content of internal script and style elements. It should be easy enough to modify this script to produce what you want. Let me know if you want it tweaked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Python script that might do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""list_assets.py"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import sys
import jsbeautifier
import copy

# Define a function to format script and style elements
def formatted_element(element):

    # Copy the element
    formatted_element = copy.copy(element)

    # Get beautified element text
    formatted_text = jsbeautifier.beautify(formatted_element.text)

    # Indent all of the text
    formatted_text = "\n".join(["    " + line for line in formatted_text.splitlines()])

    # Update the script body
    formatted_element.string = "\n" + formatted_text + "\n    "

    # Return the beautified element
    return(formatted_element)

# Load HTML from a web page
html = urllib.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()

# Parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Extract the list of external image URLs
image_urls = [image['src'] for image in soup.findAll('img') if image.has_attr('src')]

# Extract the list of external CSS URLs
css_urls = [link['href'] for link in soup.findAll('link') if link.has_attr('href')]

# Extract the list of external JavaScript URLs
script_urls = [script['src'] for script in soup.findAll('script') if script.has_attr('src')]

# Extract the list of internal CSS elements
styles = [formatted_element(style) for style in soup.findAll('style')]

# Extract the list of internal scripts
scripts = [formatted_element(script) for script in soup.findAll('script') if not script.has_attr('src')]


# Print the results

print("Images:\n")
for image_url in image_urls:
    print("    %s\n" % image_url)
print("")

print("External Style-Sheets:\n")
for css_url in css_urls:
    print("    %s\n" % css_url)
print("")

print("External Scripts:\n")
for script_url in script_urls:
    print("    %s\n" % script_url)
print("")

print("Internal Style-Sheets:\n")
for style in styles:
    print("    %s\n" % style)
print("")

print("Internal Scripts:\n")
for script in scripts:
    print("    %s\n" % script)
```

These are the (note-worthy) packages I used:

- [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to load the HTML from a web-page
- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML
- [jsbeautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to beautify/format embedded JavaScript and CSS code

The script prints the URLs for external resources and the element tags themselves (prettified/beautified) for internal resources. I made some off-the-cuff stylistic choices about how to format the results which can easily be modified or improved upon.

To see it in action, here is an example HTML file (`assets.html`):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>

<head>

    <meta charset=utf-8>

    <title>assets.html</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

    <style>
    body {
            background-color: linen;
    }

    h1 {
            color: maroon;
                    margin-left: 40px;
    } 
    </style>

    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <script>alert( 'Hello, world!' );</script>

    <img src="https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo.png">

    <p>I'm the content</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is how we might execute the script (on a local file):

```bsh
python list_assets.py assets.html
```

And here is the output:

```
Images:

    https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo.png


External Style-Sheets:

    mystyle.css


External Scripts:

    myscripts.js


Internal Style-Sheets:

    <style>
    body {
        background - color: linen;
    }

    h1 {
        color: maroon;
        margin - left: 40 px;
    }
    </style>


Internal Scripts:

    <script>
    alert('Hello, world!');
    </script>
```

Finally, here are some posts that I used as references and which you might find useful:

- [Web Scraping with Beautiful Soup](http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html)
- [Beautifulsoup to extract all external resources from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666584/beutifulsoup-to-extract-all-external-resources-from-html)
- [Checking for attributes in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003832/checking-for-attributes-in-beautifulsoup)
- [clone element with beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057631/clone-element-with-beautifulsoup)
- [BeautifulSoup4: change text inside xml tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537926/beautifulsoup4-change-text-inside-xml-tag)

Comment: This is a really useful script, I'm working with it and thanks so much for all the related links

Comment: @LuigiT. Thanks! Glad to hear it. Does it solve your problem, or do you need it to do something else?

Comment: @LuigiT. If this solves your problem, could you please accept it as your solution?

Comment: Yes it does a good part of the job, thanks again for the script